# kubelet service is not running(fluctuating) in Kubernetes master node

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubeadm

I was trying to create a Kubernetes Cluster using kubeadm. I had spin up an Ubuntu 18.04 server, installed docker (made it sure that docker.service was running), installed kubeadm kubelet and kubectl.

The following are the steps that I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker.io -y
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"
sudo apt-get install kubeadm kubelet kubectl -y
sudo apt-mark hold kubeadm kubelet kubectl 
kubeadm version
swapoff –a

sudo hostnamectl set-hostname master-node
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

Once after I ran **sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16**, I got the following error:

> root@ip-172-31-10-50:/home/ubuntu# sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
> [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.23.1
> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks
> [preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
> [preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
> [preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
> [certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
> [certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
> [certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
> [certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
> [certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
> [certs] Using the existing "sa" key
> [kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
> [kubeconfig] Using existing kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
> [kubeconfig] Using existing kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
> [kubeconfig] Using existing kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
> [kubeconfig] Using existing kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
> [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-> flags.env"
> [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
> [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
> [control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
> [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
> [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
> [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
> [etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
> [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
> [kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
> [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
> [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

I tried to run **kubectl init --pod-network-cidr** using **Flannel's CIDR(10.244.0.0/16)** and also **Calico's CIDR(192.168.0.0/16)**. However, I got the same error.

Also, I observed that the status of **Kubelet** in my EC2 instance was fluctuating. When I ran **systemctl status kubelet.service**, sometimes it was not running and sometimes the Kubelet was running. It happens automatically. Think this is what fails the **kubectl init** since the **kubelet-check** clearly says: **"It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy"**

After running **systemctl status kubelet.service**, the error:

> root@ip-172-31-10-50:/home/ubuntu# systemctl status kubelet.service
> ● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
> └─10-kubeadm.conf
> Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-12-29 17:52:35 UTC; 3s ago
> Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
> Process: 22901 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Main PID: 22901 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

And when I keep on running **systemctl status kubelet.service**, after a few seconds, the kubectl.service seems to be running and after a few seconds, it fails again.

> ...skipping...
> ● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
> └─10-kubeadm.conf
> Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-12-30 18:50:49 UTC; 125ms ago
> Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
> Main PID: 12895 (kubelet)
> Tasks: 9 (limit: 4686)
> CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
> └─12895 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf   > --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/conf

I am not sure why kubelet is fluctuating this way.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: check journal for `kubelet` logs

Comment: 1. Failed to run kubelet" err="failed to run Kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: \"systemd\" is different from docker cgroup driver: \"cgroupfs\""

2. kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  

3. kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  

4. kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.  

5. kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 45.  

6. Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the kubelet.service issue by editing **/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf**.

Within the file, I added **Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd"** and commented out **Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"**.

**/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf** for reference:

```
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
#Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

Then ran: **systemctl daemon-reload** and **systemctl restart kubelet**
This way kubelet.service was always running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error log has your answer:

> failed to run Kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "systemd" is different from docker cgroup driver: "cgroupfs""

See Kubernetes documentation on how to configure a[cgroup driver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/)